# How to display averages instead of counts on folium MarkerClusters?

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

I am using the folium package in python to display MarkerClusters for my data.

When you are not zoomed in all the way the clusters look good but they seemingly show a Count for the number of sub markers within that cluster. I understand why this is the default behavior but for my purpose I would really like the clusters to display the Average of the values for each individual marker within the given cluster for a zoom level.

Here is my code as it exists right now:

```
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[33.97810188618428, -118.2155395906348])
mc = MarkerCluster()
for p in points:
    marker = build_folium_marker(p['f_name'], p['value'], p['lat'], p['lng'])
    mc.add_child(marker)
folium_map.add_children(mc)
folium_map.save('folium_marker_cluster_map.html')
```

In an ideal world MarkerCluster would take some param that lets you sent 'count' or 'average' but that doesn't seem to be the case. I am cautiously optimistic someone will be able to suggest a reasonably simple fix that doesn't involve forking leaflet (the js library folium is built on) and editing JS source. I can't be the first person to want to show a different metric on the MarkerClusters than the sum, specifically the average of values of markers within the cluster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To customize marker cluster `icon_create_function` function is intended, the following example demonstrates how to override marker label to display custom value instead of default (count of markers in a cluster):

```
icon_create_function = '''
    function(cluster) {
        return L.divIcon({
             html: '<b>' + 123 + '</b>',
             className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-small',
             iconSize: new L.Point(20, 20)
        });
    }
'''

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(icon_create_function=icon_create_function)
```

[image]

Now comes the turn of passing custom properties via marker, in Folium default marker does not support it but the following marker class could be introduced which extends `Marker` class:

```
class MarkerWithProps(Marker):
    _template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
        var {{this.get_name()}} = L.marker(
            [{{this.location[0]}}, {{this.location[1]}}],
            {
                icon: new L.Icon.Default(),
                {%- if this.draggable %}
                draggable: true,
                autoPan: true,
                {%- endif %}
                {%- if this.props %}
                props : {{ this.props }} 
                {%- endif %}
                }
            )
            .addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
        {% endmacro %}
        """)
    def __init__(self, location, popup=None, tooltip=None, icon=None,
                 draggable=False, props = None ):
        super(MarkerWithProps, self).__init__(location=location,popup=popup,tooltip=tooltip,icon=icon,draggable=draggable)
        self.props = json.loads(json.dumps(props))
```

Now in Folium once marker object is instantiated (where `population` is a custom property)

```
marker = MarkerWithProps(
    location=marker_item['location'],
    props = { 'population': marker_item['population']}
)
marker.add_to(marker_cluster)
```

its custom properties could be accessed like this via JavaScript:

```
var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  sum += markers[i].options.props.population;
}
```

To summarize, here is an example which demonstrates how to:

- pass a custom properties via marker
- calculate average value for custom marker property per cluster marker
- display a custom label for a cluster marker

**Example**

```
#%%
import json
import folium
from folium import Marker
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
from jinja2 import Template


class MarkerWithProps(Marker):
    _template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
        var {{this.get_name()}} = L.marker(
            [{{this.location[0]}}, {{this.location[1]}}],
            {
                icon: new L.Icon.Default(),
                {%- if this.draggable %}
                draggable: true,
                autoPan: true,
                {%- endif %}
                {%- if this.props %}
                props : {{ this.props }} 
                {%- endif %}
                }
            )
            .addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
        {% endmacro %}
        """)
    def __init__(self, location, popup=None, tooltip=None, icon=None,
                 draggable=False, props = None ):
        super(MarkerWithProps, self).__init__(location=location,popup=popup,tooltip=tooltip,icon=icon,draggable=draggable)
        self.props = json.loads(json.dumps(props))    



map = folium.Map(location=[44, -73], zoom_start=4)

marker_data =(
    {
        'location':[40.67, -73.94],
        'population': 200     
    },
    {
        'location':[44.67, -73.94],
        'population': 300     
    }
)

icon_create_function = '''
    function(cluster) {
        var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            sum += markers[i].options.props.population;
        }
        var avg = sum/cluster.getChildCount();

        return L.divIcon({
             html: '<b>' + avg + '</b>',
             className: 'marker-cluster marker-cluster-small',
             iconSize: new L.Point(20, 20)
        });
    }
'''

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(icon_create_function=icon_create_function)

for marker_item in marker_data:
    marker = MarkerWithProps(
        location=marker_item['location'],
        props = { 'population': marker_item['population']}
    )
    marker.add_to(marker_cluster)

marker_cluster.add_to(map)    

#m.save(os.path.join('results', '1000_MarkerCluster0.html'))
map
```

**Result**

[image]